# Select slice consisted of several entities in NgRx Store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I use NgRx Entities to create state for '`logs`' reducer consisted of Log entities: `EntityState<Log>`. Then I want to subscribe from my Angular component to several Log entities. If it was only one Log, I would use:

```
this.store$
  .select(appStore => appStore.logs.entities[myLogId])
  .subscribe(log => someExpensiveOperation())
```

How can I select several entities and make sure subscribe fires only once if more the one of these entities has been changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit tricker than it sounds. There are two directions I have tried.

The first is to filter the list using a `map` operator. The map will be called whenever any entity changes in the list so you have to have an operator after it to ignore duplicates. Since the map will create a new array each time you can't use a standard `distinct*` operator to filter it out. I created a custom operator named `distinctElements` which is basically `distinctUntilChanged` but it does a reference check on the elements of the array rather than the array itself. For this example I assume that you are using the `selectAll` selector that is generated by the entity adapter. It exposes an array of all of the entities.

```js
const { Observable, BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;
const { startWith, pairwise, filter, map, tap } = rxjs.operators;

function distinctElements(){
    return (source) => source.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        pairwise(),
        filter(([a, b]) => a == null || a.length !== b.length || a.some(x => !b.includes(x))),
        map(([a, b]) => b)
    );
};

let state = [
  { id: 1, value: 'a' },
  { id: 2, value: 'b' },
  { id: 3, value: 'c' }
];
const store$ = new BehaviorSubject(state);

const ids = [1, 3];
store$.pipe(
  map(entities => entities.filter(entity => ids.includes(entity.id))),
  distinctElements()
).subscribe((entities) => { console.log('next', entities); });

setTimeout(() => {
  state = [...state, { id: 4, value: 'd' }];
  console.log('add entity (4)');
  store$.next(state);
}, 10);

setTimeout(() => {
  state[0].value = 'aa';
  state = [{...state[0]}, ...state.slice(1)];
  console.log('update entity (1)');
  store$.next(state);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  state = [...state.slice(0, 1), ...state.slice(2)];
  console.log('remove entity (2)');
  store$.next(state);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@rc/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

The second option would be to create separate observables for each entity and to do a `combineLatest` on all of them. For this example I assume that you are using the `selectEntities` selector that is generated by the entity adapter. This one exposes an object which is indexable by the entity's id.

```js
const { Observable, BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, timer } = rxjs;
const { startWith, pairwise, filter, map, debounce, distinctUntilChanged } = rxjs.operators;

function distinctElements(){
    return (source) => source.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        pairwise(),
        filter(([a, b]) => a == null || a.length !== b.length || a.some(x => !b.includes(x))),
        map(([a, b]) => b)
    );
};

let state = {
  1: { id: 1, value: 'a' },
  2: { id: 2, value: 'b' },
  3: { id: 3, value: 'c' }
};
const store$ = new BehaviorSubject(state);

const ids = [1, 3];
combineLatest(
  ids.map(id => store$.pipe(
    map(entities => entities[id]),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  ))
).pipe(
  debounce(() => timer(0))
).subscribe((entities) => { console.log('next', entities); });

setTimeout(() => {
  state = { ...state, 4: { id: 4, value: 'd' } };
  console.log('add entity (4)');
  store$.next(state);
}, 10);

setTimeout(() => {
  state[1].value = 'aa';
  state = { ...state, 1: {...state[1]} };
  console.log('update entity (1)');
  store$.next(state);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  state = { ...state };
  delete state[2];
  console.log('remove entity (2)');
  store$.next(state);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@rc/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Both accomplish the same thing but in different ways. I haven't done any kind of performance test to see which is better but it is probably dependent on the number of entities you are selecting relative to the total size of the list. If I had to guess I would assume that the first is more performant.

In regards to selecting a slice of projected data combining multiple slices you could reference this answer: [Denormalizing ngrx store- setting up selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246694/denormalizing-ngrx-store-setting-up-selectors/49304889)

Comment: Thanks @bygrace. I'll try the first solution. Second one (with combineLatest) would not work, as not all observed Logs have to be changed. So if I subscribed to 3 logs, but only 2 changes, I reckon combineLatest will not be executed, right? But as you mentioned in your linked article about denormalizing - if I stayed with the nested structure (I have Widgets containing Logs), I probably wouldn't have this problem, nor the one from that article. But since ngrx store should be considered as a set of db tables on client, I did normalize the store, so I don't have nested props anymore.

Comment: @tengu666 `combineLatest` wont emit until all inner observables have emitted at least once. Since the ngrx store is a BehaviorSubject they should all emit something immediately on subscribe. After that even if only one inner observable emits then `combineLatest` will emit with the last emitted value from the other inner observable. So it should work. As far as denormalizing your state, as stated in the linked answer, that isn't a suggested best practice. It is just covered for completeness. The other solutions are more relevant.

Comment: Nice, I'll try that as well. Thanks ;)